# Use Sed or Awk to add "deny from all " to a list of IP addresses

Tags: bash, sed, awk, prepend

This is probably really simple, but I'd like to find out how to add "deny from all " (with the space after "all") to a list of IP's (there are probably over 4,000).

Each line of the file contains a single IP addresses.

Answer (score 3):

Try (**not tested**):

```
sed -e 's/^/Deny from all /' infile
```

Comment: @CrAcKeDbYBiSpO: If this has answered your question, you should consider accepting it by clicking the tick to the left of this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Doing it with awk:

```
awk '{print "deny from all " $0}' < infile > outfile
```